# invalid method declaration; return type required - diffrent class name to filename

Tags: java

I need to create a quiz and when using the code at the bottom, I get the error

```
invalid method declaration: return type required
   public Q1LanguageExplorerJava()
```

Can someone explain why this occurs and how I can fix it?

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;   

class LanguageExplorerJava extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 JPanel Q1 = new JPanel() ;

 JButton Q1A1 = new JButton( "Bonjour" ) ;  
 JButton Q1A2 = new JButton( "Salut" ) ;
 JButton Q1A3 = new JButton( "Piscine" ) ;

 public Q1LanguageExplorerJava()
 {
     super( "Q1 - What is hello in French" );
     setSize( 500,200 );
     setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     add(Q1);

     Q1.add( Q1A1 ) ;           
     Q1.add( Q1A2 ) ;
     Q1.add( Q1A3 ) ;

     Q1A1.addActionListener(this);      
     Q1A2.addActionListener(this);
     Q1A3.addActionListener(this);

     setVisible( true );
 }

 public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
 {
     if( event.getSource() == Q1A1)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,"CORRECT","Message Dialog",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
         int score = 0;
         score = score+=1;
         System.out.println(score); 
     }
     if( event.getSource() == Q1A2)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,"INCORRECT","Message Dialog",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 

     if( event.getSource() == Q1A3)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this,"INCORRECT","Message 
     Dialog",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  
     }
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
         Q1LanguageExplorerJava gui = new Q1LanguageExplorerJava();
     }
    }
```

Comment: `LanguageExplorerJava`  vs `Q1LanguageExplorerJava`

Comment: Well what do you think `public Q1LanguageExplorerJava()` is? If you believe it to be a constructor, check the name against the name of the class...

Comment: Am I the only one that's even more baffled by the two if clauses doing the same thing? Plus they could be in a else? :p

Comment: The GUI needs to be started on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), per the Java Tutorial and other documentation. It would also be helpful to all concerned if you followed​ the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the code you have in your `main` method, your `Q1LanguageExplorerJava` is meant to be a constructor. However, your class is actually named `LanguageExplorerJava`, so you'll need to change either your class name or your constructor name so that they match each other.